# Looking for a sci-fi movie in which a human astronaut befriends an alien on a reddish planet

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens

This probably wasn't a blockbuster back in its time as I remember the special effects didn't seem all that bombastic, but I do remember a few details.

A human astronaut lands (or crash-lands) on a prominently reddish planet. It might have been Mars, thought it might not have been. I think the atmosphere on said planet was humanly breathable (as in the astronaut does not wear his helmet).

This human astronaut needs to survive. He spots a humanoid alien, apparently also having crash-landed or otherwise in need of survival. He sees this alien consume some sort of greenish orb, apparently for nourishment. He sneaks up to the alien (or the alien craft) in an attempt to grab some of those greenish orbs. I don't remember whether he succeeds, but he does get beaten up by the alien.

The next bit of detail I remember was the human astronaut constructing some sort of shelter to protect both him and the alien from... meteor showers? The human astronaut piles up some rocks to build a hut while the alien, apparently having learned a few English words, says "shiiiiit" and "no solid". The human astronaut asks, incredulous, "No solid?" and punches the hut he just build. "See? Solid!" he proclaims, while the hut collapses a few seconds later. The alien laughs.

Later on the human astronaut is either caught by or accidentally fell into some sort of mouth-in-the-sand creature. He is saved by the alien in the process (or was it the alien who fell into the mouth-creature and was saved by the human astronaut). They witness the mouth-creature spitting out a turtle-like shell (from another local wildlife) of some sort. The human astronaut observes, and I paraphrase, "This stuff must be so tough that even [the mouth-creature] cannot digest it!" He then proceeds to build a meteor shelter from collected shells.

The last bit of detail I remember is when the alien becomes pregnant and is dying. The human astronaut, having thoroughly befriended the alien at this point, asks (and I paraphrase), "What do you mean you're pregnant? Aren't you a male?" to which the alien responds (and again I paraphrase), "For us it comes naturally, unlike for you humans whose pregnancy only comes after a brief period of pleasure". The alien then asks the human astronaut to bring the child to the alien's home planet and recite the names of the child's ancestors in front of... alien rulers, I guess. The last scene of the movie is of the human astronaut, having arrived at the alien's home planet, standing side-by-side (or perhaps hand-in-hand) with the alien child while chanting in an alien language (what I presume to be the names of the child's ancestors).

Comment: roughly when did you watch it? was it live-action or animated?

Comment: Just to plug a nice old scifi movie, Robinson Crusoe on Mars is not what you are looking for but sort of similar plot.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

[Enemy Mine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enemy_Mine_(film)) primary source:

Crash land:

> engage in a dogfight which results in both **crash-landing** on Fyrine IV, an alien world uninhabited by intelligent life

Shelter

> After initial hostilities, the two eventually learn to cooperate to survive. They work together to build a shelter for protection against meteorite storms

Pregnancy:

> Davidge, haunted by dreams of spaceships landing on the planet, leaves in search of help. He finds evidence of humans, but learns that the planet has only been periodically visited by human miners known as "Scavengers", who use Dracs as slave labor. He returns to warn Jeriba, (nicknamed "Jerry"), only to discover that Jeriba is pregnant. (Dracs reproduce asexually).

Ending:

> In the epilogue, Davidge and Zammis return to Dracon, the Drac homeworld, for Zammis's heritage ceremony before the Drac Holy Council. As he promised Jerry, Davidge recounts the complete Jeriba ancestry before the Holy Council in the traditional ritual, as he was taught. A narrator explains that when "in the fullness of time, Zammis brought its own child before the Holy Council, the name of 'Willis Davidge' was added to the line of Jeriba."

[image: Enemy Mine]