# Film where an alien friend turns out to be traitor

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens

There was a family on a ship. There was an alien with them, the best friend of the hero.

The family died somehow, and the hero and alien are left alone, stranded on a planet.

At the end of the film the hero finds out the alien killed them on purpose, and was never their friend.

Before this reveal the alien looked gracious, mysterious and kind, but when they fight he takes his cloak off and looks really scary and carnivorous.

I remember that while they're on the planet the hero builds meteor shelters out of shells, but it does seem too similar to Enemy Mine, so maybe my memory stole that part from there.

Comment: Do you remember when you watched it? What studio it may have been? etc...

Comment: You may be mixing two movies. The "turtle shelter" scene is from Enemy Mine. But the first sentence doesn't match that.

Comment: I would agree with @BBlake; this sounds like 2 separate movies. The first part of the question with the family/team that crashes and everyone except the hero and an alien dies sounds similar to "Lost in Space" (1998): Where Will Robinson and Doctor Smith (now looking much more alien due to bug bite attained earlier in the movie) survive a fatal crash and open a portal back in time. But, the 2nd part of the question with the turtle shell shelter sounds very much like "Enemy Mine".

Comment: Thank you very much!
These were both films I've seen as a tiny child and they got mixed.

Comment: partial duplicate of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/110733/looking-for-a-sci-fi-movie-in-which-a-human-astronaut-befriends-an-alien-on-a-re and